# Extract values from first few lines then skip for reading .txt file

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr, readr

Say I have two files, file1.txt and file2.txt that looks like this:

> file1.txt

```
blablabla
lorem ipsum
year: 2007
Jan Feb Mar 
1   2   3
4   5   6
```

> file2.txt

```
blablabla
lorem ipsum
year: 2008
Jan Feb Mar 
7   8   9
10  11  12
```

I can read these files with `purrr::map_df(read_table,skip=3)`
But what I want to do is extract the year from each file and assign it on a new year column so that my final dataframe looks like this:

```
Jan Feb Mar Year
1   2   3   2007
4   5   6   2007
7   8   9   2008
10  11  12  2008
```

I am looking somewhere in the line of using `readr::read_lines` first then `readr::read_table` using `rlang::exec` but don't know how exactly to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Base R implements streaming connections with `readLines`:

```r
f <- function(path) {
    ## Open connection and close on exit
    zzz <- file(path, open = "rt")
    on.exit(close(zzz))
    ## Read first three lines into character vector and extract year
    y <- as.integer(gsub("\\D", "", readLines(zzz, n = 3L)[3L]))
    ## Read remaining lines into data frame
    d <- read.table(zzz, header = TRUE)
    d$Year <- y
    d
}

nms <- c("file1.txt", "file2.txt")
do.call(rbind, lapply(nms, f))
```

```
  Jan Feb Mar Year
1   1   2   3 2007
2   4   5   6 2007
3   7   8   9 2008
4  10  11  12 2008
```

It's not clear to me that `readr` has this functionality:

```r
library("readr")
zzz <- file("file1.txt", open = "rb")

read_lines(zzz, skip = 2L, n_max = 1L)
## [1] "year: 2007"

read_table(zzz)
## # A tibble: 0 × 0

close(zzz)
```

Even though we only asked `read_lines` for the third line of `file1.txt`, it seems to have (invisibly) read all of the lines, leaving nothing for `read_table`.

On the other hand, [this](https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/610) GitHub issue was "fixed" last year, so it is strange not to see support for streaming connections in the latest release version of `readr`. Maybe I'm missing something...?

Answer (score 0):

One other solution is use the `id` argument in `read_csv` which in  your example creates a new column with the file name (eg. "file1.txt") to show which file each row came from.

Note you don't need to use map_df, you can directly pass the file name to `read_csv()` and it will apply the read_csv to each file and compile to a dataframe.

From there, you can create new dataframe with `read_csv` of just the 3rd row eg(year:2007) again with the `id` argument and this time use `skip` and `n_max` arguments so that you only pull in the row with "year:2007".

With those two data frames you can then left join based on the column you set with the `id` argument to pull in the that row!

You will need to extract out the "year" text, which be easily done with the `str_extract()` argument.

```
df_missing_year <- readr::read_csv(file=file_path, id="source", skip=3)

df_year_only <- readr::read_csv(file=file_path, id="source",skip=2, n_max=1)

df_complete <- dplyr::left_join(x=df_missing_year, y=df_year_only, by="source")
```

If you found this helpful, please consider up voting or selecting it has the answer.