# R+Tidyverse: Tibbles don't appear to store milliseconds

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tibble

I have a CSV with many values. Among them are times stored like this:

```
1:34.434
```

Using `readr`, I form them into a tibble, and use `dplyr` to cut out all the unnecessary rows and columns.

```
lapData <- read_csv("sampledata/sampledata.csv")
lapData <- dplyr::select(lapData, 
                         Driver, Lap, Penalty, 'Lap Time', 'Lap type', 
                         'Pressure FR', 'Pressure FL', 'Pressure RR', 'Pressure RL', 
                         'Temp FR', 'Temp FL', 'Temp RR', 'Temp RL',
                         'Road Temp')
lapData <- dplyr::filter(lapData, Driver == "[personal info]")
lapData <- dplyr::filter(lapData, is.na(Penalty))
lapData <- dplyr::filter(lapData, Lap > 1)
```

I then use `print(ggplot(data = lapData, mapping = aes(Lap, 'Lap Time')) + geom_line())` to print the data, and it looks like this:
[image: plot showing loss of precision]
If it isn't clear, the vertices of the graph line are rounded to the seconds value instead of using the full milisecond precision, which I would like to have.
If I then `print(lapData)`, I see the following entries under `'Lap Time'`:
[image: printed tibble]
I did some research, and found [this](https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/883), which seems to indicate that the loss of precision in the printout from the tibble is inconsequential, and the full data is still stored in the tibble. However, the plot contradicts this statement.

How do I get the plot to show the full millisecond resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your time format doesn't agree with the time format that `readr` expects by default. Specifically, `readr` interprets `1:34.434` as 1 hour and 34 minutes, rather than as 1 minute and 34.434 seconds.

```r
text <- "id,time
1,1:23.456
2,2:34.567
3,3:45.678
"
cat(text, file = "foo.csv")

library("readr")
tt1 <- read_csv("foo.csv")
tt1
## # A tibble: 3 × 2
##      id time  
##   <dbl> <time>
## 1     1 01:23 
## 2     2 02:34 
## 3     3 03:45

as.double(tt1$time) / 60 # numbers of minutes
## [1]  83 154 225
```

The documentation suggests to use the `col_types` argument of `read_csv` to specify the time format. Normally, this *would* work:

```r
col_types <- list(id = col_integer(), time = col_time(format = "%M:%OS"))
```

But it doesn't:

```r
tt2 <- read_csv("foo.csv", col_types = col_types)
## Warning message:                                                                                                   
## One or more parsing issues, see `problems()` for details

tt2
## # A tibble: 3 × 2
##      id time  
##   <int> <time>
## 1     1    NA 
## 2     2    NA 
## 3     3    NA
```

The problem is that `readr`'s parser requires minutes to be padded with zeros:

```r
parse_time("01:23.456", format = "%M:%OS")
## 00:01:23.456

parse_time("1:23.456", format = "%M:%OS")
## Warning: 1 parsing failure.
## row col         expected   actual
##   1  -- time like %M:%OS 1:23.456
## 
## NA
```

That surprised me, because base R's parser doesn't have that constraint:

```r
strptime("1:23.456", format = "%M:%OS")
## [1] "2022-02-11 00:01:23 EST"
```

A workaround is to read the offending column as a character vector and coerce it to numeric via `strptime` after:

```r
tt3 <- read_csv("foo.csv", col_types = list(id = col_integer(), time = col_character()))
tt3
## # A tibble: 3 × 2
##      id time    
##   <int> <chr>   
## 1     1 1:23.456
## 2     2 2:34.567
## 3     3 3:45.678

library("dplyr")
tt4 <- tt3 %>% mutate(seconds = with(strptime(time, format = "%M:%OS"), 60 * min + sec))
options(pillar.sigfig = 10L)
tt4
## # A tibble: 3 × 3
##      id time     seconds
##   <int> <chr>      <dbl>
## 1     1 1:23.456  83.456
## 2     2 2:34.567 154.567
## 3     3 3:45.678 225.678
```

You can also do the coercion with `lubridate`, which has a specialized parser:

```r
library("lubridate")
tt5 <- tt3 %>% mutate(seconds = as.double(as.duration(ms(time))))
identical(tt4, tt5)
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: It seems that a leading zero is required, try `parse_time("01:23.456", format = "%M:%OS")`.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid `readr`'s guessing, you could use conventional `read.csv`.

```
r <- read.csv('foo.csv')
```

Next, it is probably better to use pure milliseconds. For this, we may use `strptime` with`"%M:%OS"` which returns the beautiful `"POSIXlt"` format that we can put in a `with` and play with the `min`utes and `sec`onds.

```
r$lap_time_ms <- with(strptime(r$lap_time, format="%M:%OS"), 6e4*min + 1e3*sec)

r
#   lap_time lap          x lap_time_ms
# 1 1:29.134   1  0.9292880       89134
# 2 1:26.233   2 -0.3301566       86233
# 3 1:28.033   3 -1.5426225       88033
# 4 1:26.434   4 -0.9961375       86434
# 5 1:26.634   5  1.1610645       86634
# 6 1:27.634   6 -0.2817558       87634
```

If you want a y-axis formatted in `<secs>:<mins>` format, use a `seq`uence along the `range` of the lap times with steps in seconds.

```
at <- do.call(seq, c(as.list(range(ceiling(r$lap_time_ms/1e3))*1e3), 1e3))
sq <- at %/% 1e3 |> {\(.) paste(. %/% 60, . %% 60, sep=':')}()

plot(lap_time_ms ~ lap, r, type='l', yaxt='n')
axis(2, at=at, labels=sq)
```

[image]

This should also be possible with `ggplot2` package.

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='lap_time
1:29.134
1:26.233
1:28.033
1:26.434 
1:26.634
1:27.634
') |> transform(lap=1:6, x=rnorm(6))
write.csv(dat, 'foo.csv', row.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: Lap times aren't really time stamps, though. The most natural class in base R is `difftime`. But then you do lose access to `axis.POSIXct` ...

Comment: @MikaelJagan You're right, it's probably better to use pure milliseconds, see my updated answer.

Comment: One way to avoid string splitting: `with(strptime(c("1:23.456", "2:34.567", "3:45.678"), format = "%M:%OS"), 60 * min + sec)`. `strptime` doesn't require minutes to be padded with zeros, hence my surprise at the fact that `readr::parse_time` does.

Comment: @MikaelJagan This is wonderful! I never realized that `strptime` actually returns `"POSIXlt"`! I've taken that up in the answer.

Comment: The more questions I [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71060773/) about `readr`, the more I dread ever having to use it... [end rant]